# Set system tray menu items to disabled when starting Tauri tray app

Tags: rust

I have a basic tray app which sets up a tray menu of custom menu items and assigns it to the app via tauri::Builder::default().system_tray.

At start up, I want all but one of the menu items to be disabled. I was unable to access a menu item method to set enabled to false, so have tried to use the tray_handle to get the item and set_enabled(false) in .setup. However, at that point the tray is not configured.

How can I set the menu item state during app set up? TIA

My current (failing) code:

```
let opt1 = CustomMenuItem::new("opt1".to_string(), "Option 1");
let opt2 = CustomMenuItem::new("opt2".to_string(), "Option 2");

let tray_menu = SystemTrayMenu::new()
    .add_item(opt1)
    .add_item(opt2);

tauri::Builder::default()
    .system_tray(SystemTray::new().with_menu(tray_menu))

.setup(|app| {
    ...

    let tray_handle = app.handle().tray_handle();
    tray_handle.get_item(&"opt1".to_string()).set_enabled(false);

    ...
})
.run(tauri::generate_context!())
.expect("error while running tauri application");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.disabled()` on your `CustomMenuItem` to set it to disabled before you add it to the menu.

Example:

```rs
SystemTray::new().with_menu(SystemTrayMenu::new()
    .add_item(CustomMenuItem::new("action".to_string(), "Loading...").disabled())
    .add_item(CustomMenuItem::new("quit".to_string(), "Quit"))
)
```

Note the `.disabled()` on the first menu item.

This code gives a menu with two items, one of which is disabled.